# How do I integrate C# Web API BasicAuthentication with IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I currently have a working C#/ASP.NET Web API program which goes through BasicAuthentication (I sent the username and passwords through HTTP Response Headers when making the HTTP Request to the Web API) to authorize users that are trying to access the API. However, when I tried to host the Web API on IIS, the Web API's BasicAuthentication gets messed up and does not trigger.

Currently, I hosted my Web API on the IIS and it appeared in my IIS Manager (Under Default Web Site, as a Application) and for authentication, the "Anonymous Authentication" is enabled, and "ASP.NET Impersonation + Forms Authentication" are disabled.

Is there anything I can do to allow my Web API's BasicAuthentication through IIS?

Edit: I have a Authorization Filter in my WebApiConfig.cs

`config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute());`

Edit: Codes used for authentication

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "BASIC " + encode);

 var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<string>("values?reason=postauth", "PostAuth");
 postTask.Wait();    
 var result = postTask.Result;
 string resultStr = postTask.Result.ReasonPhrase.ToString();
```

The string resultStr returns "Internal Server Error".

Comment: As far as I know, if you write the custom  AuthorizationFilterAttribute to achieve tte basic auth, there is no need to enable the IIS build-in basic auth. You could just enable the anynomous auth and disable other auth.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Thank you for your reply. I currently have a algorithm in the Web API Basic Authentication. Whenever a request (GET/POST/DELETE) is made, a HTTP Request header (with the encoded username and password) will follow it. Then in the API, it will retrieve a list of valid users from a text file and compare it with the encoded username and password. If it matches, the API will return 200, else, return 401 (Unauthorized). Currently, my issue is that it always returns unauthorized.

Comment: I enabled the Anonymous Authentication, and disabled the rest. Still the same. Also, I edited the post to show the authorization filter I added into my WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: UPDATE: I hosted my Web API again, and now it works fine. But when I try to make a request through my C# codes with the basic authentication key, it returns error 500 - Internal Server Error. Any suggestions on how to solve this? I updated my post with the relevant codes.

Comment: As far as I know, the 500 error means the server error. Could you please post more details error message? If the server is setting the custom error on, please set it to off. Then it will show the details error message.